# How to get detailed errors from Reporting Services Authentication Extension

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm developing Authentication Extension for SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2. It works for accessing report manager or report service using browser but trying to open a report in aspx page using `ReportViewer` control gives following error:

The Authentication Extension threw an unexpected exception or returned a value that is not valid: . (rsAuthenticationExtensionError) Get Online Help For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Is is possible to get detailed information of what happened wrong? I run it on local server machine and custom errors are Off in Report Server's web.config. Nothing is written to Application event log either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error message, for more information in these messages you need to enable remote errors for the Report Server:

[Enable remote errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337165%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

You don't mention what version you're using, so make sure to select the correct version on the MSDN page.

Once this is enabled your error messages will be more verbose. Not sure if a restart of the SSRS service is required or not, though.